# Charging from different USB cable

Tags: usb, charging

I have USB cable meant for Sony Xperia, the USB cable can be detached. Will using this USB cable to charge other phones like Nexus cause any issue?. I am not using the entire charger, I am just using the USB cable to charge through PC. Will it cause any issue to the battery in long run?

Comment: A more generic variant: [Why does my phone have erroneous input when connected to a non-OEM power source?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/39424/16575) Apart from that: No known issues concerning the *battery* itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this won't cause any issues. I am having the same case as yours (using Xperia L's USB cable with a Nexus 4) and haven't faced any issues with Nexus 4 or the Xperia.

Answer (score -3):

No issue but make sure do not use charger which is not your phone's

Comment: What's the reason for that?