# Why does the screen flicker when connecting to a third party wall mounted USB charger

Tags: usb, charging

After going through this post([Why does my phone have erroneous input when connected to a non-OEM power source?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39424/why-does-my-phone-have-erroneous-input-when-connected-to-a-non-oem-power-source)) I am asking this question the above post does not solve my question up to the mark.

I was at a convenience store where I found a wall mounted charge station. The unit has several types of pins for various brands(Lg , Nokia, Blackberry etc.) When I connected the USB to my device the screen started to flicker and the device started vibrating for some reason for which I had to withdraw the USB Cable from the device.

Specs-
Operating system-Android 4.1.2

Manufacturer-Samsung

The unit was perfectly normal as beside there was another blackberry device getting its charge normally. Then why did my device show this behaviour

Comment: The accepted answer on the question you've named IMHO exactly explains that: slightly different PIN assignments for the optional "X" PIN. Some devices might *expect* it to be grounded (and are confused if it's not), others get confused *if* it's grounded.

Comment: @Izzy Samsung devices work fine with HTC (and all other major brands of) charger cables, speaking from experience. Also I'd be surprised if they weren't using a generic cable at a *convenience store*.