# If a micro USB charger supports data transfer for one Android device, should it then support data transfer for any Android device?

Tags: usb, data-transfer

In particular, I bought "1M Micro USB Charger Charging Sync Data Cable For Samsung Galaxy S2 S3 S4 WJ" on ebay, assuming it should work with any device despite the specific brand in the title. Testing on a Huawei and a Mpie Android device, 2 of the cables do nothing, 5 only charge, 1 is detected by one device prompting option to connect as storage -- however it is not deteced on computer so effectively only charges.

Note that I have successfully data transferred with other cables on these two devices.

Failed to find info online except on distinction between charge-only and charge+data micro USB cables.

Comment: Related: [Why are USB cables of two different OEM's different](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/78397/16575) / [Micro USB cables that only charge but no data, no mounting etc (Samsung Galaxy S)](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14552/16575)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A USB cable functions the same, no matter the device. It is just 2-4 wires in a casing.

Often, cheaper cables sold on eBay using thin, low-quality wiring that breaks easily, so it is possible that you got a batch of bad cables.